# how to prevent spaces between buttons in LinearLayout Android Menu?

Tags: android, button, spaces

I have the LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout, so that I wanted to place the buttons at the top of parent layout.
I've added 4 buttons with equal relative weights ("1"), so they are all equal in size.
now it shows up like this, but I want an appearance without spaces.

[image]

Comment: Set weight sum on linear layout(android:weightsum="4") and set width match parent on every button.

Comment: It's not the answer but I think you should do this: Linearlayout should have orientation (vertical, horizontal) because the linear layout is used to organize your app and it's a easy way to do that. If your orientation is vertical, the buttons will be in top of each others.

Comment: it can achieve by simply changing button style/background.

Comment: it doesn't work. If I change the color and set android:Background=color
then entire button changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arises if you fail to set the background for the button, either set transparent or some color as a background. Please dont leave it as empty, if you do it so default button property will be assigned. I have worked out sample for you. Please try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: dear Chandru, thanks, even though the logic is a bit strange and non-convenient (because I don't understand why button's have invisible background by default..or so) but now, the buttons are not clickable.. or maybe they are, but are not changing colors during onClick.

Comment: For that purpose you have to put selector background.

Comment: Refer https://gist.github.com/granoeste/3291697 to use selector background for button

Comment: You have complete solution in developer website http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html. Please refer it. Further if you have any doubts ping me.

Answer (score 1):

Those buttons doesn't have any spaces. It is because background drawable contains transparent padding on left and on right.
Change button's background to some color (e.g. android:background="#f01123") and you will see that there is no space, between buttons.